# What MySQL privileges would a read-only drupal db user need

Tags: database

I am in the process of configuring a server that will be on the front end and will be the read-only installation.  Can anyone give me some guidance on what to look for for in regards to what tables the mysql user will need write access for... such as like access log, etc.

I am just looking for a starting point. It doesn't need to be specific.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It all depends from which modules you enable, and in which way you are going to create content. We cannot list all the tables that would need to be writable, since you are not saying which modules you are going to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the core tables of a fairly lean install, these will probably need to be writeable:

- access
- batch
- cache and cache_*
- flood
- history
- node_access
- queue
- sessions
- semaphore
- users (for last login date)
- watchdog

These I'm not too sure about, worth testing:

- registry
- registry_file
- file_usage
- blocked_ips

Contrib modules are different matter, you'll need to look at those one-by-one as it will depend on which ones you use (e.g. ctools has ctools_css_cache and ctools_object_cache)